# How to use socket.io in express as the server started?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I tried to add the following in the app.js:

```
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("a user go out");
  });

});

server.listen(3001);
```

...And test it with:

```
import websocket
print("Sensor:Initializing")
ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:3001/")
print("Sending 'Hello, World'...")
ws.send("Hello, World")
print("Sent")
```

But it returned:
`websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.`
How should I fix it?

Comment: You are using `websocket` on the client to connect to a `socket.io` powered connection. Please note that although `socket.io` uses `websocket` transport whenver possible but they are very different and one won't connect to another. You need to find a `socket.io` implementation for the language you are using. Take a look:  https://socket.io/docs/  (Other client implementations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Socket Server is correctly configured.

Problem is with with your test script. 

Websocket client is not compatible with socket-io server.

Use socket-io client to test.[Socket-io client](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```